# Applescript for Mail to check if the from email address = the reply email address

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create a rule for my incoming email to check if the **From** email address is the same as the **Reply** email address. I'm finding that a lot of the SPAM that I am getting could be filtered with this check and I'm not seeing a way to do it with the options that are in Apple Mails rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with aMessage in theMessages
                if aMessage's sender = aMessage's reply to then
                    beep
                    --insert your code here
                end if
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```